# Split a JSON object by parameters

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have a JSON Object defined in Typescript, I want to split it into parts but I can only get the keys:

This is my JSON object:

```
let data = {
  "dataTest": "data1,data2,data3",
  "insTest": "ins1,ins2,ins3",
  "serTest": "ser1,ser2,ser3"
}
```

This is what I do to loop through it:

```
for (let key of Object.keys(data)) {
  console.log(key)
}
```

This is what I get:

```
1º //dataTest
2º //insTest
3º //serTest
```

This is what I want to get:

```
1º //dataTest: "data1,data2,data3"
2º //insTest: "ins1,ins2,ins3"
3º //serTest: "ser1,ser2,ser3"
```

**Upgrade**

Is it also possible to get the concatenation of all the values in a single array?

Example:

```
data1,data2,data3,ins1,ins2,ins3,ser1,ser2,ser3
```

Comment: `for (let key of Object.keys(data)) {
  console.log(data[key as keyof typeof data])
}` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMQLwQN4CgIRgLggIjzQF80AzAewCcIAKUSAaxAE8JzSIB5AIwCsQAxmAB0TZgGcaseAEoZqDBAHkAduPKhhwcgHMpcGAG0xWcRDHsIYZgAcQl6TAC6M4kA

Comment: This returns the parameters of each key, I don't want `data1,data2,data3`, I want `"dataTest": "data1,data2,data3"` and then convert it to a URL with `URLSearchParams` and get `dataTest=data1%2Cdata2%2Cdata3`

Comment: you can build up that you have the key and the value. Use `set` if you have URL SearchParams https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Object.entries()`.

The Object.entries() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable string-keyed property [key, value] pairs.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```js
const data = {
  dataTest: "data1,data2,data3",
  insTest: "ins1,ins2,ins3",
  serTest: "ser1,ser2,ser3"
};

const entries = Object.entries(data);

entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
});
```

Comment: Ok this works fine, I put the quotes and format the url, I have updated the question with a new function related to this JSON to join them

Answer (score 0):

You can get the required value using Object.entries().

```js
let data = {
  "dataTest": "data1,data2,data3",
  "insTest": "ins1,ins2,ins3",
  "serTest": "ser1,ser2,ser3"
}

Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way

```
for(let key in data) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + '"' + data[key] + '"');
}
```

using Template literals

```
for(let key in data) {
    console.log(`${key}: "${data[key]}"`);
}
```